# How to loop over form's arraylist in jsp

Tags: jsp

I want to show data on through a loop over a arraylist of form.
Here is form

```
    public class GroupSettingForm extends BaseForm {

    private Integer groupId;
    private List<String> employeeList;   

    public Integer getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(Integer groupId) {
       this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public List<String> getEmployeeList() {
       return employeeList;
    }

    public void setEmployeeList(List<String> employeeList) {
       this.employeeList = employeeList;
    }
}
```

Here is js/

```
    function getSelectedData() {

    console.log($('#groupId').val());
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "/MSS/setting/groupSetting/edit?groupId=" + $('#groupId').val(),
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(data) {
            $('#groupId').val(data[0].groupId);
            $('#groupName').val(data[0].groupName);
            $('#employeeList').val(data[0].empList);
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is how can I loop over employeeList in jsp.[image]

The employee is always empty.
Please help.

Here is the ouput of ajax data.

[image]

Here is html code where I want to display.

```
    <c:forEach items="${employeeList}" var="employee">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <a class="delete_emp btn btn-sm btn-outline-default pl-0"><c:out value="${employee}" /><i class="fa fa-times ml-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
   </c:forEach>
```

Comment: can you share the exact output of this url /MSS/setting/groupSetting/edit?groupId=" + $('#groupId').val()

Comment: Here is the output                                                                                               >emplist:(2){"AA","BB"}                                                                  
  empListString:"AABB"                                            
  groupId:1                                                                                   
 groupName:"Group1"

Comment: Add above output in your question as well .

Comment: I've added output.

Comment: I don't know how to loop over emplist in JSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.each` to loop over your data .As you can see in below demo code :

```js
//suppose this is your data
var data = ["AA", "AB", "AC"];
//looping through array
var a = "";
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  a += '<div class="col-sm-12"><a class="delete_emp btn btn-sm btn-outline-default pl-0"> ' + item + ' <i class="fa fa-times ml-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> </div>';
});
//below will display data in div with id="add"
$("#add").html(a);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="add">
 <!--here data will come-->
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know how to show this data is JSP. I set data in ajax of script file using "$('#employeeList').val(data[0].empList);". The problem is when I loop employeeList in JSP file using foreach , the employeeList was empty. The script file and JSP file are different.

Comment: `js` and `jsp` are different , you can use ajax to show same value in your jsp .. can you add html code where you need to display this value ?

Comment: I added html code where I need to display this value to my question.

Comment: I added html code where I need to display this value to my question. I am afraid but can you check the question again please?

Comment: see update code ,same which you need to in jsp i have done using jquery ..